# How can i add + sign

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
   $numbers = array("12", "-32", "52", "-65", "98");
   $arrlength = count($numbers);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
   echo $numbers[$x];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

How can i add + sign where is not - minus.

> **Result:**
>   +12,
>   -32,
>   +52,
>   -65,
>   +98

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add condition like this:

```
echo (int)$numbers[$x] > 0 ? '+'.$numbers[$x] : $numbers[$x];
```

so it will be

```
$numbers = array("12", "-32", "52", "-65", "98");
$arrlength = count($numbers);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
echo ((int)$numbers[$x] > 0) ? '+'.$numbers[$x] : $numbers[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a very straight forwards echo modification, replace

```
echo $numbers[$x];
```

with

```
echo ( $numbers[$x] > 0 ) ? '+'.$numbers[$x] : $numbers[$x];
```